# How to allow operators in NumericFormat field in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

I am using a NumberFormat text field which allows integers only but I want to allow operators like(%, *,/,<,>,+,-,=,^).

```
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
state = { name: "" }

             <NumberFormat
              {...this.props}
              placeholder=""Enter a number
              customInput={OutlinedInput}
              value={name}
              onValueChange={(e) => handleFieldChange(e.value)}
            />

    handleFieldChangeValue = (value) => {
    this.setState({name, value})

  }
```

How can I allow the operators in this textfield?

Comment: Can you show `NumberFormat` component?

Comment: It is imported. import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";

Comment: you want to make calculations with this input?

Comment: I dont want to calculate anything, just want to store the combination of integers and the characters that I mentioned

Comment: you can use `prefix` or `suffix` props

Comment: By adding a prefix or suffix it won't help. I want to give access to user to add those characters. Eg: user can enterr '50%' or '89/6' or '>=70'

Comment: so for your purpose I believe that `react-number-format` is not what you need,
You can even do it by yourself with refex

Comment: How can I achieve that by using regex? I don't have any idea. If you could help, it would be very helpful

Comment: This is no longer a number input since none of the operators you mentioned are numbers, this is a text input. I really don't see the use of a number input here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you achieve what you need with a simple input field with `regex`:

```
import React from "react";

const regex = new RegExp('^([0-9]|[-+=^<>/%*])+$');

function App() {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const onChange = e => {
    if(regex.test(e.target.value) || e.target.value === "") {
      setValue(e.target.value);      
    };
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also check it with this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sound-qy1ck?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)